# Hardware issues on Samsung NF208 (NF210)

Tags: 10.10, hardware, ubuntu-netbook, samsung

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 10.10 running on my wife's Samsung NF208 (same spec as NF210, but shipped without OS), and I have run into a pile of problems:

- At first, there were problems with audio, display brightness, and WiFi, so I reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch. After reinstalling, the audio has started working but the WiFi loses network access all the time and then it takes 5-10 minutes for it to reconnect to the network.
- Also, display brightness is at its lowest. I have tried to use the brightness command but it won't run.

Is this system utterly incompatible with Ubuntu, or are there working WiFi and display drivers for it somewhere? I have googled for days but haven't found anything useful.

Help me.

---

**Update:** I never got it working properly. I came across lots of useful tips and tricks over at the forum linked to in the accepted answer but I just wasn't able to get it working and stable enough for the intended use. Hopefully a future version of Ubuntu and/or the samsung tools will solve that. Related thread over at the other forum: http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [Linux on my Samsung project](http://www.voria.org/forum/). They maintain a PPA with some Samsung-specific software, that solved my wifi and brightness problems (I have a Samsung netbook myself, although it's another model).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I installed the samsung tools from that site, but didn't get it working yet. Still reading more about it in their forums so hopefully the problems will be solved soon... :)